# Linux. Vim. Как узнать директорию файла, редактируемого определенной инстанцией vim?

Tags: linux, vim, i3wm

Я бы хотел составить скрипт, запускающий файловый менеджер с такой же директорией, какая мучается в определенном терминале с vim. В принципе, составлять подобные заклинания умею, но не знаю, как достать информацию о папке редактируемого файла из вимовского процесса. Не тороплюсь, буду рад любым мыслям.

Вот я редактирую один файл, потом нужно посмотреть второй в той же папке. По сочетанию клавиш запускаю файловый менеджер, и топаю ручками в папку проекта. А было бы здорово, если папка сразу была открыта нужная.

В дальнейшем бы развил идею, и если фокус не на терминале с vim, запускался бы менеджер с последней "заполненной" директорией.

Имею опыт доставания текста из заголовка активного окна. Возможно, есть какие-нибудь плагины на вим, устанавливающие такие заголовки терминала, какие мы настроим (по типу всяких airline и прочих кастомных статусных сообщений). Просто вообще пока не знаю, в какую сторону копать. Однажды-то получится, но насколько костыльным будет способ - отдельный вопрос.

NERDTree использовать не спортивно! Никаких вимовских окошек, для них у меня тайловый оконный менеджер. А вим, спустимся на землю, - всего лишь редактор, который должен быстро запускаться без плагинов и вот этого всякого.

Comment: А не проще пользовать emacs? (тогда и файловый менеджер  не нужен)

Comment: Повесь алиас на вим который будет в переменную окружения класть редактируемый файл

Comment: @avp, теперь, когда я осознал всю мощь таких тайловых оконных менеджеров, как i3wm, я "всеми ногами за" разделенные окошки. А emacs в моем понимании - это огромный монстр с кучей встроенных окон и собственными способами навигации. Зачем плодить системы (потому что это целая ОС судя по скриншотам из интернет) и нагружать мозг? Надоело активное окно - закрыл любимой комбинацией клавиш, не задумываясь, реальное ли оно, или нарисованное "внутри" программы, и повлечет ли оно за собой закрытие других окон.

Comment: @avp, с тайловым менеджером я и от вкладок браузера отказался. Открываю просто несколько окон. А уж через саму "ОС" я их размещу на экране, как мне удобно будет. Может, даже сгруппирую по вкладкам. Некоторые из них будут браузерными окнами, некоторые - терминалами, какие-то - ещё чем-нибудь. Вкладки "снаружи" браузера это, несомненно, мощная штука.

Comment: @eri, очень неплохой вариант. С виду кажется костыльным в том плане, что вим-то мне хоть кто запустит из любого скрипта, из любого удаленного рабочего стола, из любого удаленного помощника. И во всех этих сценариях нужно прописать изменение в переменную. Но это только в теории. Не часто такие "экстренные" ситуации происходят, конечно. Скорее всего, на вашем предложении и остановлюсь. Кстати, я вим часто из диспетчера файлов запускаю, так что надо будет и там прописывать.

Comment: В emacs вы тоже можете иметь столько X-window окошек, сколько пожелаете и гонять ихх по всему экрану. Можете даже работать в client-server mode и запускать новые хоть из командной строки, хоть кликая мышкой в файловом менеджере (если его окошко окажется ближе к курсру мыши)

Comment: @avp, ок, если emacs возьмет на себя всю работу тайлового менеджера, то я задумаюсь. Поддерживает ли он назначение биндов на любые кнопки (и системные), не подсунет ли свои бинды? Будет ли так же легко менять местами окна, по-прежнему нажимая alt+super+ j/k/l/; в сторону нужного окна аналогично vim-навигации? И главное, как его запускать на Линукс? Это не консольное приложение, как я погляжу, значит, нужен какой-то, блин, оконный менеджер, наверно? О, а можно ли будет включить режим resize и менять размеры окна все теми же jkl; ? Остальные окна подстроятся, заполняя оставшееся пространство?

Comment: @avp, сейчас погуглил, эта тема (связка vim + i3wm vs emacs) оказалась очень древней. Похоже, ответ что же лучше, мы никогда не найдем.

Comment: в /etc/profile я подразумевал

Comment: ну или можно сделать wrapper скрипт

Comment: @eri, wrapper - совсем недурное решение. Если я правильно понимаю, он бы "запоминал" переданные аргументы в vim. Единственное, что настораживает, в vim при использовании его не только как текстовый редактор, можно командами открыть другой файл, и случай нарушается. Хотя особо плагинами не пользуюсь, и такое развитие событий маловероятно, так что это пока лучший способ.

Comment: Заставьте vim при старте и каждой смене текущего каталога записывать новый текущий каталог в какой-нибудь файл. Читайте файл, используйте каталог.

Answer (score 0):

Установливать заголовок терминала автоматически по имени файла/директории можно опцией `title`, т.е. просто выполняете команду `set title` и получаете заголовок терминала типа `first.txt (/tmp/so-example/) - VIM`.

Из самого vim-а `expand("%:p:h")` разворачивается в полный путь к директории текущего файла. Можно использовать дальше как хочется.

Например, чтоб открыть командную строку с командой на открытие файла с заранее введенной директорией текущего файла:

`:map <F6> :let @*=expand("%:p:h")<CR>:e <C-r>*/`

Теперь после нажатия <kbd>F6</kbd> можно ввести имя нового файла используя автодополение и т.д.

[image: демонстрация]

Я использую такие мапинги, чтоб скопировать имя файла, полное/относительное имя файла или директорию в буфер обмена:

```
  " relative path  (src/foo.txt)
  nnoremap <leader>cfr :let @*=expand("%")<CR>

  " absolute path  (/something/src/foo.txt)
  nnoremap <leader>cfa :let @*=expand("%:p")<CR>

  " filename       (foo.txt)
  nnoremap <leader>cff :let @*=expand("%:t")<CR>

  " directory name (/something/src)
  nnoremap <leader>cfd :let @*=expand("%:p:h")<CR>
```

С лидером по умолчанию (`,`) нажимаю <kbd>,</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> и путь к директории скопирован в буфер обмена.

Comment: Изнутри Vim запустить *что-нибудь* проще простого, зная основы vimscript, а вот снаружи...

Копирование уже кажется серьёзным костылём в задумке, но спасибо за мысли.

Comment: Чем вас `set title` в vimrc для _снаружи_ не годится? Копирование это для демонстрации и для пользы тех, кто найдет вопрос по заголовку и (особенно) не будет читать все комментарии, где вопрос значительно уточняется.

Comment: Забыл об этом способе. Он оказался наиболее правильным. Сейчас выбираю между вашим методом, использованием wrapper'а и своим недавно найденным решением: `sudo lsof -u danil -a -c vi | grep НОМЕР_ПРОЦЕССА | grep swp`

Comment: Просто я ещё с недовольством отношусь к заголовкам окон, так как отключил их отображение, чтобы было больше места на экране, хотя всё ещё могу их просматривать, открыв статусбар оконного менеджера. Имя файла читаю в плагине вим airline.